# Vb.net appending lines of a textbox

Tags: vb.net

```
        Case 0
            MyValues(0) = InputBox("Geef de wisselkoers (> 0 en < 500) voor de Euro tov Amerikaanse dollars (1 Eur = .... Amerikaanse Dollars")
            Do Until MyValues(0) >= 0 And MyValues(0) <= 500
                MsgBox("De parameters vallen buiten de wisselkoers. Lees de text nog maals in het volgende scherm")
                MyValues(0) = InputBox("Geef de wisselkoers (> 0 en < 500) voor de Euro tov Amerikaanse dollars (1 Eur = .... Amerikaanse Dollars")
            Loop
            Wisselkoersenlistbox.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, MyValues)
        Case 2
            MyValues(1) = InputBox("Geef de wisselkoers (> 0 en < 500) voor de Euro tov Britse Ponden (1 Eur = .... Britse Ponden")
            Do Until MyValues(1) >= 0 And MyValues(1) <= 500
                MsgBox("De parameters vallen buiten de wisselkoers. Lees de text nog maals in het volgende scherm")
                MyValues(1) = InputBox("Geef de wisselkoers (> 0 en < 500) voor de Euro tov Amerikaanse dollars (1 Eur = .... Amerikaanse Dollars")
            Loop
            Wisselkoersenlistbox.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, MyValues)
```

This works now :- ) Thank you very much!!!!!
I've clicked a plus but can't give out till I reach 15 :(

Comment: Usually adding a bit of code to the description of your problem makes wonders to let us understand your situation

Comment: Appending means adding. Are you looking for replacing?

Comment: Textbox1.Text += vbNewLine & nextLineContent (??)

Comment: At the first it must be appended, but when its clicked again it needs to be replaced.

Comment: I think you are making the mistake of storing your information directly in your textbox. The information should be properly stored in variable and then use the textbox to display those variables. When a case value is changed, you would change the variable value. Then call a "write to textbox" function that'll concatenate all these variable together.

Comment: @the_lotus thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @the_lotus in comments, you're trying to store date in your text box and manipulate it there. This presents a lot of issues. Much easier to store the information in an array, update it as required and then rebuild the textbox contents any time the info changes...

```
' Declare a variable to hold your messages. I've gone with 5 here but it can be any reasonable number (or you can use ReDim to change size later if you don't know from the start)
Dim MyMessages(5) As String {"Default Values go here (if any)", "Line2", "Line3", String.Empty, String.Empty}

' Update them as required in your existing Select Case statement

Case 0
    ' ... Other code ...
    ' Update message at index 0 (Line #1) to be whatever they input
    MyMessages(0) = InputBox("Geef de wisselkoers (> 0 en < 500) voor de Euro tov Amerikaanse dollars (1 Eur = .... Amerikaanse Dollars")
Case 1
    ' ... Other code ...
    ' Update message at index 1 (Line #2) to be "Something"...
    MyMessages(1) = "Something"

' ...etc...


' Finally, update the textbox so all messages are shown one-per-line

MessageBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, MyMessages)
```

#### Re: Comments on formatting

The correct syntax for what you're trying is this...

```
Wisselkoersenlistbox.Text = String.Join(" amerikaanse Dollar" & Environment.NewLine & "1 Euro = ", MyValues)
```

Unfortunately, that's not very helpful as it only puts the string between values, not in front of the first one or after the last one.

More useful would be to simply format the variables as they're added to the array...

```
Dim format = "1 Euro = {0:0.00} amerikaanse Dollar"
Dim input = Double.Parse(InputBox("..."))
MyMessages(x) = String.Format(format, input)
```

The format string we're providing shows where to put the number and also that it should always show 2 decimal places (no more/less).

It's worth noting that working with currencies using Single or Double data types is not recommended - as the numbers get larger, the accuracy decreases (just a side-effect of [how floating point arithmetic works](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2014/09/floating-point-and-currency/)). It might be fine for displaying info / working out approximations, but you should *not* use it for anything serious, especially when results are used together and errors can compound.

As an example, try doing something like:

```
Dim Total as Double
For i = 1 to 1000000
    Total = Total + 1 / 1000000
Next i
```

Intuitively, `Total` should be exactly 1 at the end of this loop. In fact, it will be a little above or below `i`.

For currencies, use the `Decimal` data type and specify the appropriate degree of accuracy required.

Comment: thank you for the help. would it be possible to update it each time after the input has been given? For example I press case 0 give the input its being written automatically on the first line of the textbox? I then press second case and its being written on the 2nd line?
But now when I press case one again it updates the 1st line ( the above does that now :) )

Comment: Ok, your question is a little hard to follow. Have you tried the code I provided? If you do case 0 multiple times, it will keep updating Line 1. If you do case 1, it will update Line 2. `MyMessages(0) = "..."` means "update first line to be ...", `MyMessages(1)` is 2nd line, `MyMessages(2)` is 3rd, etc. You can do them in any order as many times as you like. Now, if that's not what you want, you need to explain more clearly (by editing the question to include more explanation, code, examples, etc).

Comment: thanks for your help. I had to reinstall my computer and i'll have things up and running again. I'll update my post tonigth accordingly  :)

Comment: No worries, glad I could help. If I've answered your question, please consider marking my answer as accepted using the tick on the left hand side (below the voting buttons). If you need any more clarification, please let me know

Comment: Whats the best way to write a line infront and after the value? Tried multiple things but I get errors.
Also tried changing the line to appending.

                Wisselkoersenlistbox.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, & "1 Euro = " & MyValues & "amerikaanse Dollar") ( ticked it to green for good answer!!!! )

Comment: `Dim FormattedLine = String.Format("Before {0} After", Variable)` In short, take the first parameter, replace`{0}` with the second parameter and return it as a string.